# Installing Python and Flask on ubuntu in Docker pip error

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I have installed docker using docker toolbox and details are as under

```
OS : Windows 10 Home
Docker Version : Docker version 19.03.1, build 74b1e89e8a
docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b
```

Now in ubuntu I want to install python and flask but it is not working

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python
RUN apt-get upgrade 

RUN pip install flask
RUN pip install flask-mysql
```

But I am getting an error message `/bin/sh: 1: pip: not found` I have tried with python-pip, pip3 but getting same error messaage

Pl help

Comment: Additionally install pip: `RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip`

Comment: It is not working /bin/sh: 1: python3-pip: not found

Comment: Maybe try: `FROM ubuntu:latest` at the top...

Comment: it might be working, but now it is getting problem for flask my code is RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip
RUN python3-pip install flask after this i am getting an error /bin/sh: 1: python3-pip: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c python3-pip install flask' returned a non-zero code: 127

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify it like below to use `pip3` and `python3`

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip
RUN apt-get -y upgrade 

RUN pip3 install flask
RUN pip3 install flask-mysql
```

Comment: Thanks but it is giving following error Need to get 2122 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6144 B disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Abort.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get upgrade' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: trying your code only FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip
RUN apt-get upgrade 

RUN pip3 install flask
RUN pip3 install flask-mysql

Comment: I added a `-y` in `RUN apt-get -y upgrade`

Comment: thanks it looks like working but like to mentioned few things when running i was getting warning message debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed, secondly Successfully installed PyMySQL-0.9.3 flask-mysql-1.5.1
Removing intermediate container 99821a53805f
 ---> 4d269487dc9c
Successfully built 4d269487dc9c
Successfully tagged python/flask:latest though it is successful it is not showing details in docker ps -a command? Why BTW thanks for your help